# Can someone explain why I get Fatal error C1202 here and how to address it?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to create a PPU interpreter through embedded *opcode* arrays to execute a handler to interpret the instruction. An instruction can be one of several forms (I-Form, B-Form, D-Form, X-Form, etc.) but I have a small issue with X-Form for primary opcode 31. I'm using a template class *InterpretArray* which auto-assigns handlers in an array. This class can also be used as a sub-array of handlers which can be invoked from an handler. Compiler VS2013 gives me that fatal error:

> 1>main.cpp(196): fatal error C1202: recursive type or function dependency context too complex

```
template < size_t xo_rc >
struct Interpreter < X_Form_31_XORc < xo_rc > >
```

It sounds like compiler does not like *X_Form_31_XORc*, any idea why? how can I avoid it?

Here the source that can be compiled fine if *X_FORM* is undefined:

```
#include <iostream>

#define B_FORM
//#define X_FORM

using namespace std;

// Dummy stuff

typedef unsigned int u32;
typedef signed   int s32;

union Instruction
{
#define FIELD(from, to, type) struct{ u32:(32-to-1); type:(to-from+1); u32:from; }
    u32 instruction;

    // Opcode fields
    FIELD(0, 5, u32 opcode);  // Primary opcode
    FIELD(26, 31, u32 op4);     // Extended opcode of 6-bits (up to 0x3F)
    FIELD(21, 31, u32 op4_);    // Extended opcode of 11-bits (up to 0x7FF)
    FIELD(21, 30, u32 op19);    // Extended opcode of 10-bits (up to 0x3FF)
    FIELD(27, 29, u32 op30);    // Extended opcode of 3-bits (up to 0x7)
    FIELD(21, 30, u32 op31);    // Extended opcode of 10-bits (up to 0x3FF)
    FIELD(30, 31, u32 op58);    // Extended opcode of 2-bits (up to 0x3)
    FIELD(26, 30, u32 op59);    // Extended opcode of 5-bits (up to 0x1F)
    FIELD(30, 31, u32 op62);    // Extended opcode of 2-bits (up to 0x3)
    FIELD(26, 30, u32 op63);    // Extended opcode of 5-bits (up to 0x1F)
    FIELD(21, 30, u32 op63_);   // Extended opcode of 10-bits (up to 0x3FF)

    // Instruction fields
    FIELD(30, 30, u32 aa);      // Bit/Flags: Absolute address bit
    FIELD(31, 31, u32 lk);      // Bit/Flags: Link bit: Update the link register (LR)
    FIELD(21, 21, u32 oe);      // Bit/Flags: OE bit: Enable enable setting OV and SO in the XER
    FIELD(31, 31, u32 rc);      // Bit/Flags: Record bit: Update the condition register (CR)
    FIELD(6, 6, u32 l6);      // Bit/Flags: ?
    FIELD(10, 10, u32 l10);     // Bit/Flags: ?
    FIELD(11, 11, u32 l11);     // Bit/Flags: ?
    FIELD(9, 10, u32 l9_10);   // Bit/Flags: ?
    FIELD(6, 10, u32 bo);      // Branching: Options for the branch conditional instructions
    FIELD(11, 15, u32 bi);      // Branching: CR bit to trigger branch conditional instructions
    FIELD(16, 29, s32 bd);      // Branching: Immediate 14-bit signed integer for branch displacement
    FIELD(19, 20, u32 bh);      // ?
    FIELD(11, 13, u32 bfa);     // ?
    FIELD(6, 8, u32 crfd);    // CR fields: Destination CR or FPSCR field
    FIELD(11, 13, u32 crfs);    // CR fields: Source CR or FPSCR field
    FIELD(6, 10, u32 crbd);    // CR fields: Destination bit in the CR or FPSCR
    FIELD(11, 15, u32 crba);    // CR fields: Source bit in the CR
    FIELD(16, 20, u32 crbb);    // CR fields: Source bit in the CR
    FIELD(12, 19, u32 crm);     // Identify the CR fields that are to be updated by the mtcrf instruction
    FIELD(16, 31, s32 d);       // Immediate 16-bit signed integer
    FIELD(16, 27, u32 dq);      // ?
    FIELD(16, 29, s32 ds);      // ?
    FIELD(7, 14, u32 fm);      // ?
    FIELD(6, 10, u32 frd);     // FPR: Destination
    FIELD(6, 10, u32 frs);     // FPR: Source
    FIELD(11, 15, u32 fra);     // FPR: Source
    FIELD(16, 20, u32 frb);     // FPR: Source
    FIELD(21, 25, u32 frc);     // FPR: Source
    FIELD(16, 19, u32 imm);     // Immediate for to place in FPSCR
    FIELD(6, 29, s32 li);      // Branching:
    FIELD(6, 29, s32 ll);      // Branching:
    FIELD(21, 25, u32 mb);      // First '1' bit of a 64-bit mask in rotate instructions
    FIELD(26, 26, u32 mb_);     // First '1' bit of a 64-bit mask in rotate instructions: Split field
    FIELD(26, 30, u32 me);      // Last '1' bit of a 64-bit mask in rotate instructions
    FIELD(21, 25, u32 me_);     // Last '1' bit of a 64-bit mask in rotate instructions: Split field
    FIELD(26, 26, u32 me__);    // Last '1' bit of a 64-bit mask in rotate instructions: Split field
    FIELD(16, 20, u32 nb);      // Number of bytes to move in an immediate string load or store
    FIELD(6, 10, u32 rd);      // GPR: Destination
    FIELD(6, 10, u32 rs);      // GPR: Source
    FIELD(11, 15, u32 ra);      // GPR: Source
    FIELD(16, 20, u32 rb);      // GPR: Source
    FIELD(16, 20, u32 sh);      // Shift amount
    FIELD(30, 30, u32 sh_);     // Shift amount: Split field
    FIELD(11, 20, u32 spr);     // Special-purpose register
    FIELD(9, 10, u32 strm);    // ?
    FIELD(20, 26, u32 lev);     // ?
    FIELD(16, 31, s32 simm);    // Immediate 16-bit signed integer
    FIELD(16, 31, u32 uimm);    // Immediate 16-bit unsigned integer
    FIELD(9, 10, u32 th);      // Data stream variant of the dcbt instruction
    FIELD(6, 10, u32 to);      // Trap conditions
    FIELD(6, 10, u32 vd);      // Vector/SIMD: Destination vector register
    FIELD(6, 10, u32 vs);      // Vector/SIMD: Source vector register
    FIELD(11, 15, u32 va);      // Vector/SIMD: Source vector register
    FIELD(16, 20, u32 vb);      // Vector/SIMD: Source vector register
    FIELD(21, 25, u32 vc);      // Vector/SIMD: Source vector register
    FIELD(22, 25, u32 vshb);    // Vector/SIMD: Specifies a shift amount in bytes
    FIELD(11, 15, s32 vsimm);   // Vector/SIMD: Immediate 5-bit signed integer
    FIELD(11, 15, u32 vuimm);   // Vector/SIMD: Immediate 5-bit unsigned integer
#undef FIELD
};

struct PPUThread {}; // register context but we do not need it here

// Opcode part

// auto-initialize by recursively assigning all handlers in an opcode array 
template< template< typename > class Handler,
          template< size_t   > class Indexer,
          size_t                     start_index,
          size_t                     end_index >
struct OpcodeArrayRange
{
    template< typename Owner >
    static __forceinline void initialize(Owner & owner)
    {
        owner.array[start_index] = Handler< Indexer< start_index > >::handle;
        OpcodeArrayRange< Handler, Indexer, start_index + 1, end_index >::initialize(owner);
    }
};

// auto-initialize by assigning the last handler in an opcode array 
template< template< typename > class Handler,
          template< size_t   > class Indexer,
          size_t                     start_index >
struct OpcodeArrayRange < Handler, Indexer, start_index, start_index >
{
    template< typename Owner >
    static __forceinline void initialize(Owner & owner)
    {
        owner.array[start_index] = Handler< Indexer< start_index > >::handle;
    }
};

template < size_t po >
struct OPCD // Primary opcode, used for Indexer in OpcodeArrayRange
{
};

#ifdef B_FORM

template < size_t po >
using B_Form = OPCD < po >;

template < size_t bo_bi >
struct B_Form_BOBI
{
};

#endif

#ifdef X_FORM

template < size_t po >
using X_Form = OPCD < po > ; // Primary opcode + Extended opcode + Record bit

template < size_t po, size_t xo, size_t rc >
struct X_Form_XO_Rc // Primary opcode + Extended opcode + Record bit
{
};

template < size_t po, size_t xo_rc >
struct X_Form_XORc // glue Extended opcode and Record bit into one field, used for Indexer in OpcodeArrayRange
{
};

template < size_t xo_rc >
using X_Form_31_XORc = X_Form_XORc < 31, xo_rc > ; // alias to X_Form_XORc with Primary opcode 31

#endif

// Interpreter part

template< typename T >
struct Interpreter
{
};

// generic interpreter array
template< template< size_t > class OpcodeFormat,
          size_t                   start_index,
          size_t                   end_index >
struct InterpretArray :
    OpcodeArrayRange < Interpreter, OpcodeFormat, start_index, end_index >
{
    InterpretArray()
    {
        initialize(*this);
    }

    __forceinline void operator()(size_t      index,
                                  Instruction code,
                                  PPUThread&  thread)
    {
        array[index](code, thread);
    }

    void(*array[1 + end_index - start_index])(Instruction, PPUThread&);
};

// implementation for interpreting opcodes

template< size_t po >
struct Interpreter < OPCD < po > >
{
    static void handle(Instruction /*code*/, PPUThread& /*thread*/)
    {
        std::cout
            << "OPCD #"
            << po
            << std::endl;
    }
};

#ifdef B_FORM

template < size_t bo_bi >
struct Interpreter < B_Form_BOBI < bo_bi > >
{
    static void handle(Instruction code, PPUThread& thread)
    {
        std::cout
            << "OPCD #31, BO #"
            << (bo_bi >> 5)
            << ", BI #"
            << (bo_bi & 31)
            << ", AA #"
            << (code.aa)
            << ", LK #"
            << (code.lk)
            << std::endl;
    }
};

static InterpretArray < B_Form_BOBI, 0, 0x3FF > interpret_B_Form_BOBI;

template< >
struct Interpreter < B_Form < 16 > >
{
    static void handle(Instruction code, PPUThread& thread)
    {
        interpret_B_Form_BOBI((code.instruction >> 16) & 0x3FF, code, thread);
    }
};

#endif

#ifdef X_FORM

template < size_t xo_rc >
struct Interpreter < X_Form_31_XORc < xo_rc > >
{
    static void handle(Instruction /*code*/, PPUThread& /*thread*/)
    {
        std::cout
            << "OPCD #31, XO #"
            << (xo_rc >> 1)
            << ", Rc #"
            << (xo_rc & 1)
            << std::endl;
    }
};

// specific interpreter array for instructions selected by their extended code
// and Record bit when primary opcode is 31
static InterpretArray < X_Form_31_XORc, 0, 0x7FF > interpret_X_Form_31;

template< >
struct Interpreter < X_Form < 31 > > // note that X_Form is an alias to OPCD
{
    static void handle(Instruction code, PPUThread& thread)
    {
        interpret_X_Form_31((code.instruction & 0x7FF), code, thread);
    }
};

#endif

// specific interpreter array for instructions
// selected by primary opcode
static InterpretArray < OPCD, 0, 0x3F > interpret;

int main()
{
    Instruction insn;
    PPUThread   thread;

    {
        insn.opcode = 2;
        interpret(insn.opcode, insn, thread);
    }
#ifdef B_FORM
    {
        insn.opcode = 16;
        insn.bo = 2;
        insn.bi = 3;
        insn.aa = 1;
        insn.lk = 1;
        interpret(insn.opcode, insn, thread);
    }
#endif
#ifdef X_FORM
    {
        insn.opcode = 31;
        insn.op31 = 2;
        insn.rc = 0;
        interpret(insn.opcode, insn, thread);
    }
    {
        insn.opcode = 31;
        insn.op31 = 2;
        insn.rc = 1;
        interpret(insn.opcode, insn, thread);
    }
#endif
}
```

EDIT: I added B_Form which is similar to X_Form but not using alias and it works (but building is quite slow).

Comment: I added B_Form which is similar to X_Form but not using alias and it works (but building is quite slow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> template< template< typename > class Handler,
>           template< size_t   > class Indexer,
>           size_t                     start_index,
>           size_t                     end_index >
> struct OpcodeArrayRange
> {
>     template< typename Owner >
>     static __forceinline void initialize(Owner & owner)
>     {
>         owner.array[start_index] = Handler< Indexer< start_index > >::handle;
>         OpcodeArrayRange< Handler, Indexer, start_index + 1, end_index >::initialize(owner);
>     }
> };
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
> template< template< size_t > class OpcodeFormat,
>           size_t                   start_index,
>           size_t                   end_index >
> struct InterpretArray :
>     OpcodeArrayRange < Interpreter, OpcodeFormat, start_index, end_index >
> ```
>
> ...
>
> ```
> static InterpretArray < X_Form_31_XORc, 0, 0x7FF > interpret_X_Form_31;
> ```

The instantiation of `InterpretArray < X_Form_31_XORc, 0, 0x7FF >` triggers the instantiation of its base class `OpcodeArrayRange < Interpreter, X_Form_31_XORc, 0, 0x7FF >`.

The instantiation of `OpcodeArrayRange < Interpreter, X_Form_31_XORc, 0, 0x7FF >` triggers the instantiation of `OpcodeArrayRange < Interpreter, X_Form_31_XORc, 1, 0x7FF >`, because of how you defined your `initialize` method.

The instantiation of `OpcodeArrayRange < Interpreter, X_Form_31_XORc, 1, 0x7FF >` triggers the instantiation of `OpcodeArrayRange < Interpreter, X_Form_31_XORc, 2, 0x7FF >`, because of how you defined your `initialize` method.

The instantiation of `OpcodeArrayRange < Interpreter, X_Form_31_XORc, 2, 0x7FF >` triggers the instantiation of `OpcodeArrayRange < Interpreter, X_Form_31_XORc, 3, 0x7FF >`, because of how you defined your `initialize` method.

etc.

This recursive instantiation of templates is subject to limits. You've exceeded your compiler's limit (as well as GCC's and clang's). You probably simply shouldn't be referring to other template instantiations in your `initialize` method.

Comment: So I think AndyG (did he erase his comment? why?) was right with limitation with `using` when in vc2012/2013 because if I try to build with the online compiler (http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/) which is vc2015+, I do not get this error but compiler halted because building was taken too much time.

Comment: @hlide The maximum allowed template instantiation depth may have been changed in VC2015. From the comments on [C++11/14 Features Tables For Visual Studio 14 CTP1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/06/11/c-11-14-feature-tables-for-visual-studio-14-ctp1.aspx): "IIRC, the compiler's limit is 500. N3936's suggested limit is 1024 or greater, so I'll ask the compiler team to consider changing this." - Stephan T. Lavavej

Comment: I build B_FORM (1024 iterations) under vc2013 (limit : 500 iterations) with no fatal error. Your remark is right in the case I mentioned above (because I really had this issue) but not for the one you answered. I think it is because there is no recursive instantiation here probably because it is just a static function calling another static function and not an instantiation of a recursively derived class.

Comment: I never spoke of a recursively derived class. A recursively derived class is one possible instance in which you get recursively instantiated templates, but not the only one.

Comment: After some trials, I think the answer is very close to explain my issue (still an uncertainty about the exact limit number) and so I validate it